# Convert date given from GMT+0 to current time zone

Tags: java, android, timezone

I have response from API in ISO "2013-09-20T00:00:00Z" witch is GMT+0 and i need to convert it to device's current time zone.

Comment: The thing you are new in android has nothing with date you want to transform. Use Google to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse it. It looks like the format would be yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX

The 'X' indicates use of the ISO 8601 time zone.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String s = "2013-09-20T00:00:00Z";
    Calendar c = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(s);
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    s = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(c);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier with Joda-Time.

```
String input = "2013-09-20T00:00:00Z";
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, DateTimeZone.getDefault() );
```